# Is it possible to pick only error entry from logfiles in logstash

Tags: logstash

I am using logstash to monitor my production server logs, but it throws all logs from info to errors, what I want is that it can only pick errors from log file and throw it on logstash kibana view.

Answer (score 0):

After parsing your log using `grok` you can use [logstash conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) to check if `loglevel` (or whatever is your field name) equals to `ERROR`. If its true forward it to your output plugin,

```
output {
  if [loglevel] == "ERROR"{   # Send ERROR logs only 
    elasticsearch {
    ...
    }
  }
}
```

If you are using filebeat to ship logs, you can use [Processors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/5.3/configuration-processors.html), to send only logs that [contains](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/5.3/configuration-processors.html#condition-contains) `ERROR`.

> The contains condition checks if a value is part of a field. The field
>   can be a string or an array of strings. The condition accepts only a
>   string value.
>
> For example, the following condition checks if an error is part of the
>   transaction status:

```
contains:
  status: "Specific error"
```

Depends on your log format, you might be able to use one of the many supported conditions by filebeat processors,

> Each condition receives a field to compare. You can specify multiple
>   fields under the same condition by using AND between the fields (for
>   example, field1 AND field2).
>
> For each field, you can specify a simple field name or a nested map,
>   for example dns.question.name.

You can read more about [Conditions here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/5.3/configuration-processors.html#conditions)

Comment: Yes I am using filebeat and have three saperate file for input filter and output. Will definitely try you solution.